# Font in fonts.dir not available in xfontsel or gvim

Tags: vim, fonts, x11, suse

I am working to add some fonts containing devicons to my $HOME dir for use in vim and gvim.  vim needs the font in the terminal so I'm trying this command and get a `xterm: unable to open font <name>, trying "fixed"` error:

```
xterm -u8 -fn '-misc-knack-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-15'
```

I see that specified font in the fonts.dir file and I've refreshed my cache with `fc-cache -f -v`.  fc-list shows `Knack:style=NerdFontPlusOcticonsPlusPomicons` but using that string yields the same result.  xfontsel does NOT show this as an available font but gvim does show this font as an option.

Why does the font appear in fonts.dir (and fonts.scale) but not in xfontsel?

Why does gvim see the font but not X11?

Shell is tcsh on a Suse11 system.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
-misc-knack-bold-i-normal--0-0-0-0-p-0-iso8859-15
```

is a *scalable* font as described in [`mkfontdir`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/mkfontdir.1.html), because all of the sizes are zeros.  `xterm` and `xfd` need sizes.  You can experiment with

```
#!/bin/sh
FONT=`xfontsel -print`
test -n "$FONT" && xfd -fn "$FONT
```

to see what sizes the font server would like to deliver for a non-scaled version of the font, or use the name from `fc-list` with the `-fa` option of [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) and `xfd`:

> **`-fa`** *pattern*
>   This option sets  the  pattern  for  fonts  selected  from  the
>   *FreeType*  library if support for that library was compiled into
>   xterm.  This corresponds to the **`faceName`** resource.  When a  CJK
>   double-width  font  is  specified, you also need to turn on the
>   **`cjkWidth`** resource.

Further reading:

- [X Logical Font Description](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_Logical_Font_Description) (Arch wiki)
- [Appendix A. Specifying Fonts](http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/XLib_PG/sgi_html/apa.html) (SGI developer books)
- [Appendix A. Specifying Fonts: Scalable Fonts](http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/Irix_6.5.21_doc_cd/usr/share/Insight/library/SGI_bookshelves/SGI_Developer/books/XLib_PG/sgi_html/apa.html#S1-1002-A-3)